# Which Tantric scripture classifies the Agamas into SAttvic, RAjasic and TAmasic categories?

Tags: scripture, tantra, agamas, gunas

It is a well known fact that the PurAnas have a classification based on the TriGunAs (Sattva, Rajas and Tamah). That is, there are SAttvic PurAnas, RAjasic PurAnas and TAmasic PurAnas.

Now, for the Agamas too, there seems to exist a similar classification.

In the book " Hymn to KAli" (which is the English translation of SwAmi VimalAnanda's commentary on the famous Stotra to Goddess DakshinA KAlikA called the "KarpurAdi Stotra"), the author Arthur Avalon writes:

> The autummal Durgapuja and other Vratas are performed according to the
>   Puranas. But initiation, Upasana of Brahman with Sakti and various
>   practices of Yoga are done according to the ritual of the Agama
>   Sastra. **This latter is of three kinds according to the prevalence of
>   the Gunas namely Tantra, Yamala and Damara**. There are in all 192
>   Agamas current, namely 64 each in Asvakranta, Rathakranta, and
>   Vishnukranta. Many Tantras were lost in Buddhist and Mahommedan times
>   and the few which still remain with Sadhakas in different parts of the
>   country are not shown by them to any but to their disciples, so that
>   these also are about to be lost. The late
>   Rasika-Mohana-Chattopadhyaya, with great effort and cost, saved some
>   of these and the English Arthur Avalon has done the same and I hope
>   yet others will in future be rescued by him.

So, what it says is that- the Tantras (like KulArnava, Nila, NirvAna, Niruttara, MahAnirvAna, VAmAkeswara etc) are Sattvik Agamas. The YAmalas (like Rudra YAmalam, Vishnu YAmalam, BrahmA YAmalam, UmA YAmalam, Bhairava YAmalam etc) are RAjasic Agamas whereas the DAmaras (like Bhoota DAmara etc) are the TAmasic Agamas.

**In which scripture (possibly in Agamas) is this classification found? Looking for the verse.**

Comment: Not as per Damaras, Yamalas etc. But the second Ulhassa of [parmananda tantra](https://archive.org/details/ParamanandaTantraRaghunathMishra/page/n31/mode/2up) from the 21st verse gives a classification of tantras based on Gunas.