# have any scriptures other than Puranas been classified based on Gunas?

Tags: scripture, gunas, classification

Puranas are supposed to have one of three gunas - Sattva, Rajas and Tamas.  Commentators like Ludo Rocher have found this classification to be "fanciful".

have other categories of scripture like Brahmanas, Upanishads etc. have been classified along similar lines?

Comment: Tantras/Agamas too apparently has [such a classification](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22172/which-tantric-scripture-classifies-the-agamas-into-sattvic-rajasic-and-tamasic)

Comment: that seems to be just the opinion of Arthur Avalon @rickross .

Comment: No, he is well read in the Tantras so such a verse actually exists somewhere. I am also looking to know exactly where.